# Python OOO coding with parent child relationship

Tags: python

I have a parent and child class. Parent class has 2 attributes x,y. Y can be set to private variable with __(double underscore) but I can't expose it to the child class, so I have given it as a _(single underscore) exposing it to the child class.

But I don't want it to be exposed other than the child class..

Is there anyway to override the init class in the child method to protect the y variable being exposed?

test.py

```
class parent:

    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x = x
        self._y =   ' '
        self.setyvalue()

    def setyvalue(self):
        self._y = 10
        return self._y 
class child(parent):
    def test(self):
        print('self.x',self.x)
        print('self._y',self._y)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = child(2)
    x.test()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By convention, a variable beginning with an underscore is considered as "private", and it shouldn't be used outside the class. Python doesn't prevent it, but it's the convention that should be respected. This is the way you do in Python: everything is allowed, but you document how it should be used.

Answer (score 2):

No.  Python doesn't provide a way to really hide attributes; it just provides conventions to discourage inappropriate access.  Using the single underscore is a convention that marks it as private and warns users that if they use that variable they're risking disaster.

Note that even the double-underscore "hiding" isn't very strong security.  if your class Foo has an attribute `__blah`, it can still be accessed by outsiders as `_Foo__blah`.  Again, it's just a convention that discourages outside access but doesn't prevent it.